# How to declare the additional richer object representations provided by IPython?

Tags: python, latex, ipython, pretty-print

For a Python object, one can declare a textual representation using the `__repr__` method. From what I have read, Ipython extends this and allows the us to declare richer representations like: HTML, JSON, PNG, JPEG, SVG, LaTeX.

My question is: How can one declare this richer representations for a given object? Is it something like:

```
def display_latex(self):
```

I'm particularly interested in displaying a LaTeX representation of an object, but I prefer to keep the focus of the question for all possible representations to attract a broader audience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/github.com/ipython/ipython/raw/master/examples/notebooks/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb) is one example that shows you how to do it both by modifying the class and by registering an object.

To respond directly, you need to create a `_repr_latex_` or register a TexFormater of object of type `YourType`. In future versions, repr will support arbitrary mimetypes.